# Adding one decimal place in javaScript

Tags: javascript

I am needing to change the value 543 to 5.43 in javascript.

I have tried: `543.toFixed(2);` but that resulted in 543.00

How can I change 543 to 5.43 in javascript?

Comment: How would you do it in real life?

Comment: what would you like to do with 540?

Comment: Add one decimal place from the left? Or add one decimal 2 places from the right

Comment: The answer comes from grade school arithmetic.

Comment: `543 / 100;` quite simple.

Comment: Well sorry I'm not an expert. Some people forget that they started from this point as well. Not knowing everything and anything about everything. Give me some slack. And RELAX. But thank you for providing me with an answer.

Comment: I would expect someone who's coding to be able to do simple arithmetic. Now, maybe you know how to divide but didn't know in JavaScript, in which case you could Google how to divide in JavaScript instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Divide by 100.  543 and 5.43 are completely different numbers...

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure this is your answer or not, but please see code below

```
// just simply divide by 100
(543/100).toFixed(2);

// for any value
var value = 543;
var length = value.toString().length;
(value/Math.pow(10, length-1)).toFixed(2);
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

Divide it by 100, i.e 543/100=5.43. If you do 543 % 100 it will give 43, its modular division gives remainder

Comment: Sorry, this just took you way too long.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple.

```
sqrt(543*543)/(10^2).
```

This will get you the desired result of 5.43

Comment: lol **most** correct? It's the same as nhfrif's answer. Don't get full of yourself because you did division.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, by the way. I wouldn't do that since your answer is still correct.

Comment: Fine how about this: sqrt(543^2)/(10^2). Sufficiently complicated enough to impress a client but actually very simple.

Comment: `^` is the XOR operator in JavaScript

Comment: `Math.pow`. Also, -1 because that’s too complicated ;)